# Importing text into PANDAS and counting certain words

Tags: python, performance, pandas

**Aim:** To improve the speed of the following code. Current timing is about 80~ hours :0

**Purpose:** The code imports a dataset which contains 1.9 million rows and two columns. One of these columns contain text posts of var length. I then loop through each of these *rows* and query the post against an imported function that returns a specific counter of *variable length*. The counter tells me about the presence of certain words in the text. On average the func takes less than  1 ms to return this counter. (Timer for the "Func" inserted at the end to prove this)

**Overheads:** The code i'm looking to improve is the loop. I accept a certain level of overhead with the "func" which can't be improved at this minute. I have considered looking at Spark or Dask to parallelize the loop and speed up the process. Suggestions are welcome

```
#Import data
import pandas as pd 
from func import func 
data = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')

print(len(data))
>> 1900000

print(data.columns)
>> Index(['type', 'body'], dtype='object')


#Create new DF
data2 = pd.Dataframe()

for post in data['post']:
    post = str(post)
    scores = func.countWords(posts)
    data2 = data2.append(scores,ignore_index=True)

print(scores)
>> Counter({0: 306,
     1: 185,
     2: 61,
     45: 31,
     87: 23,
     92: 5,
     94: 3,
     102: 30,})


 import time
 start = time.time()
 score = func.countWords("Slow down Sir, you're going to give yourself skin faliure!")
 end = time.time()
 print(end - start)
 >> 0.0019948482513427734
```

Comment: Any appreciable speedup here will come from optimizing countWords - I"d advise that you post that function for review.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9280/review-that-targets-code-that-makes-the-question-off-topic-then-question-is-upd)

Answer (score 0):

Several errors:

> I then loop through each of these loops

I take it you mean "I then loop through each of these columns".

> for post in data['post]:

missing end quote mark

> scores = Func.countWords(posts)

You imported `func` (lowercase) and now you're calling `Func` (uppercase)

> data2 = data2.append(scores,ignore_index=True)

`append` should take a row-type object. If the function returns a numeric, then you shouldn't be appending it. Instead you can do:

```
def post_to_count(post):
      return func.countWord(str(post))

scores = data['post'].apply(post_to_count)
```

Comment: I've fixed those spelling and syntaxs errors. Your .apply works fine, but 1) it returns a combined dataframe, 2) does it increase speed up?

Comment: What about `scores = data.post.str.apply(func.countWord)`?

Comment: Hey there, you've answered the question in a state when it was off-topic for the site. In accordance with [existing site policy](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7051/37660) the edit to the question that makes your answer basically moot is acceptable. Considering that your answer in it's current state doesn't really contain a lot of useful suggestions for the latest revision of the post, you may want to [edit] your answer to avoid downvotes (or the answer being deleted). For more information, see [this meta discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9280/37660). Thanks!